# How do I apply cumulative sum to a numpy column based on another column having the same values?

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy arrays with the following structure:

```
array([[ 113.555   , 1506.      ],
       [ 113.595   , 1460.      ],
       [ 113.605   , 3900.      ],
       [ 113.605   , 3002.      ],
       [ 113.612   , 3434.      ],
       ...
       [ 113.6351  , 2095.      ]])
```

And I would like to group the values of column two for those rows with the same value in first column.

So the above would become:

```
array([[ 113.555   , 1506.      ],
       [ 113.595   , 1460.      ],
       [ 113.605   , 6902.      ],
       [ 113.612   , 3434.      ],
       ...
       [ 113.6351  , 2095.      ]])
```

and will have one less row. The order shall be respected. The arrays are always ordered by the first column.

Which would be the numpy way of implementing this? Is there any method from the API that can be used?

I have tried to iterate and check for the previous value, but it does not seem like the right way to do it in numpy.

Comment: Could this be something you would like to have? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html As you can turn on the indices to recieve a list of the indexes you can then filter on the indexes.

Comment: I still do not see how to combine unique to do the cumulative sum, could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sounds like a job for pandas, which can do things like ```groupby(column).sum()```

Comment: thanks Homer512, it is useful to know that the easiest way would be Pandas. Just from the point of view of learning further numpy, could the same thing be achieved more or less easily in numpy?

Comment: If the array contains computed floating point numbers, either method will be unreliable.

Comment: I just want to avoid exact duplicates

Comment: `uni, inv = np.unique(data[:,0], return_inverse=True); np.dstack((uni, np.bincount(inv, data[:,1])))` is the equivalent of @Homer512 `df.groupby` for sorted data. That would be a lot of work if there's only one duplicate row guaranteed.

Comment: There is no groupby in Numpy though this is a long standing request from developers. If values are not contiguous, you need 2 indirect sorts (assuming you want data not to be reordered) including a (slow) argsort and it is quite a pain to do with Numpy (and in the end it is not efficient either). Numpy is not really designed for that (yet) so it is not the right tool.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny that was a typo, I updated the description, the array is always sorted

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I guess I saw this one. I am not sure there is something more recent but I did not found one. The provided repository https://github.com/ml31415/numpy-groupies seems like a good one currently (mainly based on Numba).

Comment: If you are fine with using scipy, you could use ```np.unique``` and then convert the whole thing into a sparse matrix with one row per unique entry, one column per entry. Do a rowwise sum or ```matrix @ np.ones(rows)``` to get the partial sums

Comment: Thanks I would explore numpy-groupies (which looks very good) and scipy sparse matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dictionary comprehension:

```html
a = np.array([[ 113.555   , 1506.      ],
       [ 113.595   , 1460.      ],
       [ 113.605   , 3900.      ],
       [ 113.605   , 3002.      ],
       [ 113.612   , 3434.      ],
       [ 113.6351  , 2095.      ]])
       
       
np.array([[key, value] for key, value in iter({i[0]:i[1] if a[c][0]!=a[c-1][0] else a[c][1]+a[c-1][1] for c,i in enumerate(a) }.items())])

Output:
```

[image]

Comment: This is not efficient as it uses the slow CPython interpreter by default (and it will be relatively slow even with PyPy). It is better to use native solution or the one using JIT internally. Also note that hash-based solution are quite good only when the number of unique entries is small compared to the total number of entries. Sort-based solutions should be faster in this case (unfortunately the sort of Numpy is not great here).

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty simple solution that randomly occurred to me. We can use the normal cumulative sum as a building block. I'll explain the idea before showing the code.

Consider this example:

```
keys   = [0,  0,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3]
values = [1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8]
```

We compute the cumulative sum over the values:

```
psums  = [1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36]
```

The values that interest us are the last values per sequence of equal keys (plus the very last value). How do we get this? In scalar code, `keys[i] != keys[i + 1]`, in vectorized form `keys[:-1] != keys[1:]` (plus the very last value).

```
keys   = [0,  0,  1,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3]
psums  = [1,  3,  6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36]
              ^   ^           ^       ^
diffs  = [0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  1]
ends   = [3,  6, 21, 36]
```

Now it should be easy to see that the final result that we want is the difference between the value and its predecessor, except for the first value. `np.append(ends[0], ends[1:] - ends[:-1])`

Putting this all together:

```py
arr = np.array([[ 113.555   , 1506.      ],
                [ 113.595   , 1460.      ],
                [ 113.605   , 3900.      ],
                [ 113.605   , 3002.      ],
                [ 113.612   , 3434.      ],
                [ 113.6351  , 2095.      ]])
keys = arr[:, 0]
values = arr[:, 1]
psums = np.cumsum(values)
diffs = np.append(keys[:-1] != keys[1:], True)
ends = psums[diffs]
sums = np.append(ends[0], ends[1:] - ends[:-1])
result = np.stack((keys[diffs], sums), axis=-1)

result = array([[ 113.555 , 1506.    ],
                [ 113.595 , 1460.    ],
                [ 113.605 , 6902.    ],
                [ 113.612 , 3434.    ],
                [ 113.6351, 2095.    ]])
```

### Warning

This approach is numerically unstable when used for floating point. A small sum at the end of the list is computed as the difference of two large partial sums. This will lead to catastrophic cancellation.

However, for integers it works fine. Even with overflow, the wrap-around ensures that the final result is okay.

Comment: I am wondering on the impact on performance of the append there. I finally used numpy-groupies package.

Comment: @M.E. Yeah, that is a bother if there are many groups and these arrays become large. The more efficient but verbose approach would be using the ```out``` parameter with an ```np.empty``` array. Like this ```diffs = np.empty(len(keys), dtype='bool'); np.not_equal(keys[:-1], keys[1:], out=diffs[:-1]); diffs[-1] = true```